# How to populate a 2d array?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have the following code that (nearly) populates a list of lists (I will call it a 2d array) in Python.

Instead of going up from 0-6 and repeating this 3 times, I want it to populate the array with numbers 0 - 20. Please see code below:

```
#matrix=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[8,9,10,11,12,13,14],[15,16,17,18,19,20,21]
#print(matrix[1][2])

rows=3 
columns=7 

for i in range(rows):
  for j in range(columns):
    matrix=[j]
    i=i+1    
    print(matrix,end="")
```

The erroneous output is:

```
[0][1][2][3][4][5][6][0][1][2][3][4][5][6][0][1][2][3][4][5][6]
```

I want the output to be:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[8,9,10,11,12,13,14],[15,16,17,18,19,20,21]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are fancier ways, but this is the most straightforward:

```
>>> rows = 3
>>> columns = 7
>>> n = 1
>>> matrix = []
>>> for _ in range(rows):
...     sub = []
...     for _ in range(columns):
...         sub.append(n)
...         n += 1
...     matrix.append(sub)
...
>>> matrix
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]]
```

And for good measure, a fancy way:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> counter = itertools.count(1)
>>> rows = 3
>>> columns = 7
>>> matrix = [[n for n, _ in zip(counter, range(columns))] for _ in range(rows)]
>>> matrix
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]]
>>>
```

Comment: Are you able to comment your solutions. Such as the use of _in - I Have never come across before. Is sub creating a new sublist that is then appended - it seems all so unnecessarily complex. In VB.Net for instance, this could be done so simply .....

Comment: `_` is merely a variable name like any other, just like `foo`. However, by convention it is used for *throwaway* variables, i.e. I never actually use it. And yes, that is *exactly* what `sub` is doing. Python lists are *lists* not multidimensional arrays. If you want array-like functionality, use *actual arrays* like `numpy.ndarray`, where this would simply be `matrix = numpy.arange(rows*columns).reshape(rows, columns)`

Comment: thank you. It may be that I will have to use numpy, as part of the requirement is being able to use arrays (to teach them). As you say Python does not support the use of arrays in the true sense of the word (lists can contain elements of different types). Is there any reason why people keep saying "numpy" is too complex/overkill for beginners? It seems easier than options above and use of list comprehension.

Comment: @MissComputing Python *does* support true arrays, you can use the `array` module. But it is quite limited. `numpy` is a full-fledged multidimensional array library on steroids, with *many many* built-in methods for performing numerical calculations (**num**py). With plain python `array.array`, you have to implement the multidimensional functionality yourself. That being said, actually *using* arrays is usually considered more difficult than using lists, and often, a list is what you need. But what do you mean "to teach them"?

Comment: @MissComputing What will you be using these arrays for? If it involves linear algebra, numpy is the way to go. If built correctly, it will have some BLAS backend making linear algebra very fast (e.g. matrix multiplication)

Comment: My subsequent question, pertaining to the use of these arrays is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44445051/creating-a-2d-numpy-array-to-hold-characters

Comment: The hope was to create a numpy array to store characters, and subsequently "read in" words, letter by letter into the array. Documentation is more geared toward, as you say, mathematical stuff

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44445051/creating-a-2d-numpy-array-to-hold-characters  (how to use numpy to store characters)

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension. You want 3 rows so the base of the list comprehension is: `[for y in range(rows)]`. You want to have incrementing numbers starting with a number divisible by columns but starting from 1 so: `range(columns*y+1,...)` and you want to have columns range (7) so `range(columns*y+1,columns+(columns*y+1))` and then turn that into a list.

```
rows=3 
columns=7 

matrix=[list(range(columns*y+1,columns+(columns*y+1))) for y in range(rows)]

print(matrix)
#outputs: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]]
```