# Creating a 2d numpy array to hold characters

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following numpy array and previous set up that has a word queue and a temporary variable 'temp' to store a word. This word needs to be "put", letter by letter, into the numpy 2d array:

```
from collections import deque
import numpy as np 
message=input("Write a message:")
wordqueue=message.split()
queue=deque(wordqueue)
print(wordqueue)

for i in range(1):
  temp=wordqueue.pop(0) #store the removed item in the temporary variable 'temp'
print(wordqueue)
print(temp)
display = np.zeros((4,10)) #create a 2d array that is to store the words from the queue
print(display)
display[0, 0] = temp #add the word from the temp variable to fill the array (each character in each sequential position in the array)
print(display)
```

Unfortunately, the output is as follows:

```
Write a message: This is a message for the display array
['This', 'is', 'a', 'message', 'for', 'the', 'display', 'array']
['is', 'a', 'message', 'for', 'the', 'display', 'array']
This
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 20, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'This'
```

I did try to define the 2d array and define the data type, but that too wasn't very obvious and I kept getting various errors.

What I would like help with is the following: 
1. Ideally, I would like the numpy array to be set up with "*"s instead of zeros/ones (the documentation didn't help with this setup). 
2. Replace the *s in the array with the temp variable. One letter for each *

EXAMPLE:

Display array:
 (4 x 20)

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

Enter Message: This is a test message
temp: This

Updated display would show:

```
t h i s * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

for subsequent words, it would then populate the array (truncating if the word was too big and going to the next line if necessary)

So far:
https://repl.it/IcJ3/7

I tried this, for instance, to create the char array:

```
display = np.chararray((4,10)) #create a 2d array that is to store the letters in the words from the queue
display[:]="*"
```

but it produced this, with the erroneous "b" inserted. Cannot see why ...

```
[[b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*']
 [b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*']
 [b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*']
 [b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*' b'*']]
```

Updated (working on )repl.it here:
https://repl.it/IcJ3/8

Comment: the code, if anyone wants a quick play, is here: https://repl.it/IcJ3/7

Comment: `np.zeros((4,10))` creates an array of floats.  You need to specify at `dtype`, such as `s1` to hold strings.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned, I note the error, but am still struggling, despite trying (see updated repl.it: https://repl.it/IcJ3/8 ) to get it to work. Have used a char array, and even more peculiar errors

Comment: have you try out a combination of numpy chararray(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.chararray.html), and numpy full (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.full.html)?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned, the latest update above , and this https://repl.it/IcJ3/8 shows what I'm attempting - and I've used exactly the sites you've mentioned. What I'm after is someone to point out the errors/show how to fix them please. For instance, what on earth is that inserted b?

Comment: It's not "inserted"; note that the `b` that you see is before the quotes. It's the representation of a `bytes` string in Python 3. Similarly, `u'*'` is the repr of a `unicode` string in Python 2.

Comment: `b'*'` denotes a bytestring in python 3.  Use 'U1'` to hold a default Py3 unicode single character string.  Also don't use `np.chararray`.  Regular arrays with the correct `dtype` are better.

Comment: Do you want one character per element of the array, or one word?

Comment: one character, not one word - sorry not to be clear

Comment: hpaulj- "Use U1" - could you possibly show me how to insert that into my existing code - I'm not sure what you mean. https://repl.it/IcJ3/8

Comment: Show us the output that you want (or at least part of it).  How do you want to map a list of words onto a 4x10 array of characters?  You don't have 40 words or exactly 40 characters, do you?  The words don't all have 10 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from a string to a list to an array containing one word per element:

```
In [402]: astr = "This is a message for the display array"
In [403]: alist = astr.split()
In [404]: alist
Out[404]: ['This', 'is', 'a', 'message', 'for', 'the', 'display', 'array']
In [405]: arr = np.array(alist)
In [406]: arr
Out[406]: 
array(['This', 'is', 'a', 'message', 'for', 'the', 'display', 'array'], 
      dtype='<U7')
In [407]: arr.shape
Out[407]: (8,)
```

I'm using PY3, so the dtype is `U7`, chosen automatically by `np.array` to be big enough to hold the largest string in the list.

For an array to hold single characters:

```
In [408]: carr = np.zeros((4,10), 'U1')
In [409]: carr
Out[409]: 
array([['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
       ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
       ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
       ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']], 
      dtype='<U1')
In [410]: carr.fill('*')
In [411]: carr
Out[411]: 
array([['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
       ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
       ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
       ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*']], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

Make an array of single characters from the string:

```
In [430]: np.array(list(astr))
Out[430]: 
array(['T', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'm', 'e', 's',
       's', 'a', 'g', 'e', ' ', 'f', 'o', 'r', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', ' ',
       'd', 'i', 's', 'p', 'l', 'a', 'y', ' ', 'a', 'r', 'r', 'a', 'y'], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

Mapping the list of words on to single character array is a bit more tedious.  `This` goes into the `arr[0,0:4]`, etc.

---

Here's a way of mapping a list of words onto an array:

```
In [462]: alist
Out[462]: ['This', 'is', 'a', 'message', 'for', 'the', 'display', 'array']
In [463]: ''.join(alist)                     # back to one string
Out[463]: 'Thisisamessageforthedisplayarray'
In [464]: np.array(list(''.join(alist)))     # a flat array of char
Out[464]: 
array(['T', 'h', 'i', 's', 'i', 's', 'a', 'm', 'e', 's', 's', 'a', 'g',
       'e', 'f', 'o', 'r', 't', 'h', 'e', 'd', 'i', 's', 'p', 'l', 'a',
       'y', 'a', 'r', 'r', 'a', 'y'], 
      dtype='<U1')
In [465]: _.shape
Out[465]: (32,)
```

or I could copy the list of characters onto an existing array (using `flat` to treat it as 1d):

```
In [466]: arr = np.zeros((4,10), 'U1')
In [467]: arr.flat[:32] = list(''.join(alist))  
In [468]: arr
Out[468]: 
array([['T', 'h', 'i', 's', 'i', 's', 'a', 'm', 'e', 's'],
       ['s', 'a', 'g', 'e', 'f', 'o', 'r', 't', 'h', 'e'],
       ['d', 'i', 's', 'p', 'l', 'a', 'y', 'a', 'r', 'r'],
       ['a', 'y', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

and if I throw in blanks between words:

```
In [471]: arr.flat[:39] = list(' '.join(alist))
In [472]: arr
Out[472]: 
array([['T', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' '],
       ['m', 'e', 's', 's', 'a', 'g', 'e', ' ', 'f', 'o'],
       ['r', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'd', 'i', 's', 'p'],
       ['l', 'a', 'y', ' ', 'a', 'r', 'r', 'a', 'y', '']], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I would not have got that - much googling was done! I have this https://repl.it/IcJ3/14 and the last bit is just figuring out how to write each character in the temp variable to the array. Thank you

Comment: I'd like to select this as the answer but I'm still not entirely sure how to go from what I have here: https://repl.it/IcJ3/17 to the answer that you've displayed as an Output ......

Answer (score 6):

First thing is first, if you want a "character" array, you have to be careful with what exactly you expect. In Python 3, strings are now sequences of *unicode code points*. In Python 2, strings were the classic "sequence of bytes" strings from languages like C. This means, that from a memory pov, unicode types can be much more memory intensive:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: chararray = np.zeros((4,10), dtype='S1')

In [3]: unicodearray =  np.zeros((4,10), dtype='U1')

In [4]: chararray.itemsize, unicodearray.itemsize
Out[4]: (1, 4)

In [5]: chararray.nbytes
Out[5]: 40

In [6]: unicodearray.nbytes
Out[6]: 160
```

So if you know you want to work only with ascii-characters, you can use the `S1` dtype cut your memory use to 1/4th. Also note, that since `S1` in Python 3 actually corresponds to the `bytes` data type (which is equilvaent to Python 2 `str`), the representation is prepended by a `b`, so `b'this is a bytes object'`:

```
In [7]: chararray
Out[7]:
array([[b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b''],
       [b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b''],
       [b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b''],
       [b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'']],
      dtype='|S1')

In [8]: unicodearray
Out[8]:
array([['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
       ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
       ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
       ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']],
      dtype='<U1')
```

Now, suppose you have some payload you want to assign a message to your array. If your message consists of characters that are representable as ascii, then you can play fast and loose with the dtype:

```
In [15]: message = 'This'

In [16]: unicodearray.reshape(-1)[:len(message)] = list(message)

In [17]: unicodearray
Out[17]:
array(['T', 'h', 'i', 's', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
       '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
       '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
      dtype='<U1')

In [18]: chararray.reshape(-1)[:len(message)] = list(message)

In [19]: chararray
Out[19]:
array([[b'T', b'h', b'i', b's', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b''],
       [b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b''],
       [b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b''],
       [b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'', b'']],
      dtype='|S1')
```

However, if that is *not* the case:

```
In [22]: message = "กขฃคฅฆงจฉ"

In [23]: len(message)
Out[23]: 9

In [24]: unicodearray.reshape(-1)[:len(message)] = list(message)

In [25]: unicodearray
Out[25]:
array(['ก', 'ข', 'ฃ', 'ค', 'ฅ', 'ฆ', 'ง', 'จ', 'ฉ', '', '', '', '', '', '',
       '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
       '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
      dtype='<U1')

In [26]: chararray.reshape(-1)[:len(message)] = list(message)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-7d7cdb93de1f> in <module>()
----> 1 chararray.reshape(-1)[:len(message)] = list(message)

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0e01' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

In [27]:
```

Note, if you want to initialize the array with an element other than what it defaults to with `np.zeros` you can use `np.full`:

```
In [27]: chararray = np.full((4,10), '*', dtype='S1')

In [28]: chararray
Out[28]:
array([[b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*'],
       [b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*'],
       [b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*'],
       [b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*', b'*']],
      dtype='|S1')
```

Finally, to do this long-form with for-loops:

```
In [17]: temp = "a test"

In [18]: display = np.full((4,10), '*', dtype='U1')

In [19]: display
Out[19]:
array([['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
       ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
       ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
       ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*']],
      dtype='<U1')

In [20]: it = iter(temp) # give us a single-pass iterator
    ...: for i in range(display.shape[0]):
    ...:     for j, c in zip(range(display.shape[1]), it):
    ...:         display[i, j] = c
    ...:

In [21]: display
Out[21]:
array([['a', ' ', 't', 'e', 's', 't', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
       ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
       ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
       ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*']],
      dtype='<U1')
```

An another test for good measure, that spans rows:

```
In [36]: temp = "this is a test, a test this is"

In [37]: display = np.full((4,10), '*', dtype='U1')

In [38]: it = iter(temp) # give us a single-pass iterator
    ...: for i in range(display.shape[0]):
    ...:     for j, c in zip(range(display.shape[1]), it):
    ...:         display[i, j] = c
    ...:

In [39]: display
Out[39]:
array([['t', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' '],
       ['t', 'e', 's', 't', ',', ' ', 'a', ' ', 't', 'e'],
       ['s', 't', ' ', 't', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's'],
       ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*']],
      dtype='<U1')
```

**Warning** The order of the arguments passed to `zip` matters, since `it` is a single-pass iterator:

```
zip(range(display.shape[1]), it)
```

It should be the last argument, or else it will skip characters between rows!

Finally, note that `numpy` provides a convenience function for iterating over arrays sequentially:

```
In [49]: temp = "this is yet another test"

In [50]: display = np.full((4,10), '*', dtype='U1')

In [51]: for c, x in zip(temp, np.nditer(display, op_flags=['readwrite'])):
    ...:     x[...] = c
    ...:

In [52]: display
Out[52]:
array([['t', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'y', 'e'],
       ['t', ' ', 'a', 'n', 'o', 't', 'h', 'e', 'r', ' '],
       ['t', 'e', 's', 't', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
       ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*']],
      dtype='<U1')
```

There is a minor complication of having to pass a `op_flags=['readwrite']` to the function to make sure that the iterator that is returned allows modification to the underlying array, but it greatly simplifies the code and we don't need to use a single-pass iterator. I still prefer slice assignment, though.

Comment: This is all hugely helpful information, thank you. I'm not sure the question as to how to fill the numpy array with characters from the message using the temp variable is/was addressed though. Basically the question is to: for every character in the temp variable, go through the array sequentially and fill the spaces (replaces the asterxies with the respective letters in the message) ....this being what I have so far: https://repl.it/IcJ3/17

Comment: @MissComputing I've *already done that here:* `chararray.reshape(-1)[:len(message)] = list(message)`. This is using slice-assignment instead of a loop. Note, your for-loop doesn't make much sense. First, since your arrays are two-dimensional, and you want to touch each item in the array sequentially, you will need some sort of nested loop. Also, you shouldn't be assigning to `display[0, 0]` since that will always assign to the *first* element on every iteration. I've updated the answer with an example of using nested loops to achieve the same thing as the slice assignment.

Comment: @MissComputing note, I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with a `deque`, but there really isn't a need since strings are iterable, and they iterate over characters.